# Creating group ids by comparing values of two variables across rows: in R

Tags: r, sorting, grouping

I have a dataframe with two variables (`start`,`end`). would like to create an identifier variable which grows in ascending order of `start` and, most importantly, is kept constant if the value of `start` coincides with `end` of *any other row* in the dataframe.

Below is a simple example of the data

```
toy_data <- data.frame(start = c(1,5,6,10,16),
                      end = c(10,9,11,15,17))
```

The output I would be looking for is the following:

```
output_data <- data.frame(start = c(1,10,5,6,16),
                   end = c(10,15,9,11,17),
                   NEW_VAR = c(1,1,2,3,4))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adapting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65923646/3460670) to group by ranges that are adjacent to each other. Credit goes entirely to @r2evans.

In this case, you would use `expand.grid` to get combinations of `start` and `end`. Instead of labels you would have row numbers `rn` to reference.

In the end, you can number the groups based on which rows appear together in the list. The last few lines starting with `enframe` use `tibble`/`tidyverse`. To match the group numbers I resorted the results too.

I hope this might be helpful.

```
library(tidyverse)

toy_data <- data.frame(start = c(1,5,6,10,16),
                       end = c(10,9,11,15,17))

toy_data$rn = 1:nrow(toy_data)

eg <- expand.grid(a = seq_len(nrow(toy_data)), b = seq_len(nrow(toy_data)))
eg <- eg[eg$a < eg$b,]

together <- cbind(
  setNames(toy_data[eg$a,], paste0(names(toy_data), "1")),
  setNames(toy_data[eg$b,], paste0(names(toy_data), "2"))
)

together <- subset(together, end1 == start2)

groups <- split(together$rn2, together$rn1)

for (i in toy_data$rn) {
  ind <- (i == names(groups)) | sapply(groups, `%in%`, x = i)
  vals <- groups[ind]
  groups <- c(
    setNames(list(unique(c(i, names(vals), unlist(vals)))), i),
    groups[!ind]
  )
}

min_row <- as.numeric(sapply(groups, min))
ctr <- seq_along(groups)

lapply(ctr[order(match(min_row, ctr))], \(x) toy_data[toy_data$rn %in% groups[[x]], ]) %>%
  enframe() %>%
  unnest(col = value) %>%
  select(-rn)
```

**Output**

```
   name start   end
  <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1    10
2     1    10    15
3     2     5     9
4     3     6    11
5     4    16    17
```

Comment: Just curious, how is this approach more efficient than my approach?

Comment: Hi @Dion - I'm really not sure about all of this or what the best method might be - there is some uncertainty remaining on how the output might look like under different circumstances. My approach was thinking of a way to get at overlap or near-overlap between rows and groups. I think our approaches are different. For example, if the last row had `start` of 15 instead of 16, I would have grouped with the first group (1-10, 10-15, 15-17). I suppose it might help with more clarification from the OP?

Comment: Thanks @Ben for the answer! Clarification of the OP is best in all instances for sure :) When `start` would take the values (1, 10, 5, 6, 15)<sup>T</sup>, I think the output the OP wants is `[1] 1 1 2 3 3`. But maybe I am wrong on this.

Comment: Thanks a million @Ben @Dion! I feel more confortable with `tidyverse` than with `base` R but even the approach using `tidyverse` is quite too advanced for my current knowledge of R so I decided to stick with Stata for this challenge at the time being - thanks a lot for your help on this!

Answer (score 1):

The following function should give you the desired identifier variable `NEW_VAR`.

```
identifier <- \(df) {
  x <- array(0L, dim = nrow(df))
  count <- 0L
  my_seq <- seq_len(nrow(df))
  for (i in my_seq) {
    if(!df[i,]$start %in% df$end) {
      x[i] <- my_seq[i] + count
    } else {
      x[i] <- my_seq[i]-1L + count
      count <- count - 1L
    }
  }
  x
}
```

Examples

```
# your example
toy_data <- data.frame(start = c(1,10,5,6,16),
           end = c(10,15,9,11,17))
toy_data$NEW_VAR <- identifier(toy_data)
# ---------------------
> toy_data$NEW_VAR
[1] 1 1 2 3 4

# other example
toy_data <- data.frame(start = c(1, 2, 2, 4, 16, 21, 18, 3),
                       end = c(16, 2, 21, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1))
toy_data$NEW_VAR <- identifier(toy_data)
# ---------------------
> toy_data$NEW_VAR
[1] 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2
```